# lein run, won't run -main correctly, though a clean nrepl will

Tags: clojure, leiningen

New to clojure, trying to compile the following code, for a boolean expression evaluator

```
;core.clj
(ns my-app.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn t [& args] (if (empty? args) t
                 ((first args) t (first (rest args)))))

(defn f [& args] (if (empty? args)  f
                 ((first args)  f (first (rest args)))))

(defn | [cond1 cond2] (if (= cond1 t) t
                      (if (= cond2 t) t f)))

(defn & [cond1 cond2] (if (= cond1 f) f
                      (if (= cond2 f) f t)))

(defn ! [& args] (if (= (first args) t)
               (apply f (rest args))
               (if ( = (first args) f)
                 (apply t (rest args))
                 (! (apply (first args) (rest args))))))


(defn -main [& args]
 (loop [line (read-line)]
   (do
      (println (eval (read-string (apply str "" (interpose \space  (seq (str "(" line ")")))))))
  (if (= (count line) 1) nil (recur (read-line))))))
```

Everytime I do "lein run" and enter the string "(t|t)=t" I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: t in this context
```

However If I open up a new nrepl in the "src/my_app/" dir, and enter the command

```
(-main)
```

I get the correct string and result

```
( ( t | t ) = t )
true
```

I should note, that while running lein run

the other strings string "+ 1 2 3 4 5 6" will evaluate correctly, but for some reason it won't recognize the function (t ...)

Anybody have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` uses the current (thread-bound) value of `*ns*` to determine what namespace you're currently "in", which controls how unqualified symbols are resolved.  At the repl after running `(ns my-app.core ...)`, you're in the `my-app.core` namespace and thus eval finds the `t` you've defined there.  However after compilation even though you still defined `t` in `my-app.core`, when your program begins running you're in the `user` namespace and eval fails to find `t`.

So all you need to do is change your namespace within `-main` to be `my-app.core`, using `binding` like this:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (binding [*ns* (the-ns 'my-app.core)]
    (loop [line (read-line)]
      (println (eval (read-string (apply str (interpose \space (str "(" line ")"))))))
      (when-not (= (count line) 1)
        (recur (read-line))))))
```

Comment: Thank you, that completely fixed everything.